# How to match regex with starting index in the middle of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a parser and I'd like to avoid chopping up the input string for performance reasons. Thus, I've created a `Stream` object that represents the string with a cursor:

```
const Stream = (string, cursor) => Object.freeze({
  string,
  cursor,
  length: string.length - cursor,
  slice: (start, end) => string.slice(start + cursor, end ? start + end : undefined),
  move: distance => stream(string, cursor + distance),
})
```

I want to be able to use regular expressions to match against this string. However, I don't care about anything in before the cursor. So suppose I have the following string and cursor:

```
> string = 'hello ABCD'
'ABCD'
> cursor = 6
6
```

So we don't care about anything before the `A`, but we want to be able to use regex to match all those uppercase letters:

```
> re = /^[A-Z]+/
/^[A-Z]+/
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work. I noticed when you use the `g` flag, then you can use `RegExp.exec` and it will keep track of a `lastIndex` property. But then the `^` match will not start at `lastIndex`...

Any ideas how I can get this to work efficiently? If I have to use a 3rd party regex library, I'm fine with that, but ideally this could be done with the native RegExp...

Comment: Why not use something like `^.{6}[A-Z]+`?

Comment: oooh. thats an interesting idea... its still going to iterate a bunch of times though `^.{10006}[A-Z]+`

Comment: Sure it's going to iterate that many times, but have you measured a performance problem?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have not measured, but its the difference between `O(n)` and `O(n^2)`...

Answer (score -2):

I would do with sed:

```
sed -rn 's/^.{'$cursor'}([A-Z]+)$/\1/p'
```

where $cursor is a shell variable containing the number of ignored chars at the beginning.

Option `-r` is extended regexp, `-n` is do not print always, `p` is print if match.

Now the question is how to port that to your language. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression#comment32878607_494046) you have some hints of how to use variables in regular expressions in Javascript.